# Rest api php upload image does'nt work in the postman, method "POST"

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have followed the tutorial "[Android Upload Image using Android Upload Service](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/)" but it doesn't work.

I have implemented the postman software, but there is still no response?

This is my version of the code:

dbConfig.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Heri Prastio
 * Date: 27/12/2018
 * Time: 21:40
 */
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DB','db_images');
?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Heri Prastio
 * Date: 27/12/2018
 * Time: 21:43
 */
//Importing dbConfig.php
require_once 'dbConfig.php';


//My folder uploads images
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

$upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/AndroidImageUpload/' . $upload_path;

$respon = array();

//I don't understand this part of the code
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die("Unable to connect");

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;
        $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

        try {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file_path);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images_table('id','url','name') values (NULL , $file_url, '$name');";
```

This is the complete source code link: ([upload.php](https://gist.github.com/heri56/2ad0afc4fa87d6a7b8a5621d784d32b7))

This is a picture of the implementation of the postman software, there is no response.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU74X.png)

Comment: Well, you really ought to be checking for Mysqli errors. For one, your insert query would fail because column names should be surrounded by backticks or not at all, and your file_url should be quoted, or preferably use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for your values.  Do some troubleshooting by echoing/logging along the way to see where it's going and what it's doing.

Comment: I have worked on Image upload  API and tested on PostMan. I would suggest convert the image to Base64 string, retrieve that and then save in your POST call. Also make sure all your headers (specially if there is login functionality) are there in PostMan

Comment: @aynber Solved, but I get an error, mysqli_fetch_array() error message expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in. Then I change this function with mysqli_result Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result(). Why does the error in that section continue to experience repeated error messages? Please help me and explain?

Comment: Then it's still failing. Check for errors right after you execute your query, because it's returning false instead of a mysqli_result object.